# How do I have my menu overlap everything?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a vertical navigation that drops down to the right when I hover over page names that offer subpages. when I hover over, it appears beside it but the content appears on top of it. I want my navigation to be on top of everything. I tried using z-index. I used 32, 999, 1000, 10000 for my z-index. I tried switching my menu from position:absolute to position:relative but it just adds unwanted space. I tried setting my content to position:absolute with a z-index, lower than the one in my navigation. Here is the link:
http://michellecantin.ca/test/

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative position of your container div a the problem. Float it to the right instead:

```
#container {
   position: relative;
   left: 26%;
   width: 72%;
}
```

should be:

```
#container {
   float:right;
   width: 72%;
}
```

Comment: @MichelleCantin can you elaborate?